# Filter some values from sqllite database in android

Tags: android

Hi i had fetched all datas from the database and now i have to filter the data by matching its email id and display the filtered data in the listview but i am facing problem as i am getting the first value repeated again and again. please help me i am new in android and i am stuck on this.
I am also sending my code.

```
for(int i = 0;i<C_parts.size();i++){
    if(C_parts.get(i).email.toString().equals(Global.useremailid.toString()))
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ACCOUNT, new String[] { ACCT_NAME,
                    ACCT_HEAD_NAME, OPEN_BAL, EMAIL }, EMAIL + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(Global.useremailid) }, null, null, null,
                    null);
            System.out.println("value of cursor:->"+cursor);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToNext();

                String acc_name = cursor.getString(0);
                String acc_head_name = cursor.getString(1);
                String openbal = cursor.getString(2);
                String amail=cursor.getString(3);
                System.out.println("bfr accountid:->"+acc_name);
                System.out.println("bfr accountname:->"+acc_head_name);
                System.out.println("bfr headname:->"+openbal);


            C_parts1.add(new Account(acc_name,acc_head_name,openbal, amail));
        }
    }


                c_adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, C_parts1);


            if (list1 == null)
                list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv1);
            list1.setAdapter(c_adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(list1);
            list1.invalidate();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(int i = 0;i<C_parts.size();i++){
    if(C_parts.get(i).email.toString().equals(Global.useremailid.toString()))
```

to

```
for(int i = 0;i<C_parts.size();i++){
if(C_parts.get(i).email.toString().equals(Global.useremailid.toString())) {
```

Your Cursor code will be executed only if equals, but the other code will be always executed and since the cursor is the same of the previous iteration it will repeat the same data.

It's because if you don't add `{ }` after a `if` only the first line will be part of the if.

---

Same here

```
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToNext();

            String acc_name = cursor.getString(0);
            String acc_head_name = cursor.getString(1);
            String openbal = cursor.getString(2);
            String amail=cursor.getString(3);
            System.out.println("bfr accountid:->"+acc_name);
            System.out.println("bfr accountname:->"+acc_head_name);
            System.out.println("bfr headname:->"+openbal);


        C_parts1.add(new Account(acc_name,acc_head_name,openbal, amail));
    }
```

add a `{` after `if (cursor != null)` and make sure every `{}` are OK.

Comment: @user2009847 I rolled back your edit because it was a Radical Change. If you wish to answer a question, please do so below by clicking "Post Your Answer" but not by editing other people's answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Sankarann - [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4638011) should not have been approved as it was clearly a radical change.

Comment: @Hemang - [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4638011) should not have been approved as it was clearly a radical change.

Comment: @Deekey- [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4638011) should not have been approved as it was clearly a radical change.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    String acc_name = cursor.getString(0);
                    String acc_head_name = cursor.getString(1);
                    String openbal = cursor.getString(2);
                    String amail=cursor.getString(3);
                    System.out.println("bfr accountid:->"+acc_name);
                    System.out.println("bfr accountname:->"+acc_head_name);
                    System.out.println("bfr headname:->"+openbal);
                    System.out.println("bfr email:->"+amail);

                C_parts1.add(new Account(acc_name,acc_head_name,openbal, amail));
                System.out.println("value of c_parts1 on for loop:->"+C_parts1.toString());
                }
```